# Showing the compactness of a limit operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was trying to solve this exercise from Kreyszig's book, section 8.1 exercise number 10. My attempt was try to show that the operators in the sequence are bounded, but I don't find it. If this fact were possible, then we can apply Theorem 8.1.4 (Finite dimensional domain or range) to the $T_n$ showing that these operators are compact and after use the theorem 8.1.5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

> Let $Y$ be a Banach space and let $T_n:X\rightarrow Y$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, be operators of finite rank. If $(T_n)$ is uniformly operator convergent, show
>   that the limit operator is compact.

Comment: The fact that they are bounded must be missing in the hypothesis - else you can just take a constant sequence consisting of a discontinuous linear functional, for instance.

Comment: Whoops, I accidentally assumed $T_n$ to be continuous. Is it wrong, OP?

Comment: I have the same doubt Silvia, but thanks for your answer, tomorrow I'm going to analyse your answer and the sugestions. Thanks for all @Silvia Ghinassi

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Prahlad Vaidyanathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't necessarily use the theorems you refer to (I don't own that book), but this is the one proof I used to know. Hope it helps you anyway. Remember that in a complete metric space, totally bounded (having finite $\varepsilon$-net for any $\varepsilon$) and relatively compact are the same.

I also assumed that your $T_n$ are continuous (i.e. bounded in this case), because, as mentioned in the comments, if they're not the result is false. My apologies if this is not the answer you needed.

---

To show that $T$ is a compact operator we will show that $T$ is continuous and that $T(K)$ is relatively compact for $K \subset X$ bounded.

Since $T$ is a uniform limit of continuous operators, it is also continuous. In fact, for any $x \in X$, so we have
\begin{align}
\| T(x) - T(y) \| &= \| T(x) -T_n(x) + T_n(x) - T_n(y) + T_n(y) - T(y)\| \leq \\
& \leq \| T(x) - T_n(x)\| + \| T_n(x) - T_n(y)\| + \| T_n(y) - T(y)\|  \to 0
\end{align}
if $\| x-y\| \to 0$, since $T_n$ is continuous (middle term) and $T_n \to T$ uniformly (first and third term).

Let $K \subset X$ be a bounded subset.
Since $T_n(K)$ is relatively compact in $Y$ Banach, it has a finite $\frac{1}{n}$-net $y_i$, so we have, for $x \in K$,
$$
\| T(x) - y_i \| \leq  \| T_n(x) - T(x)\| + \| T_n(x) - y_i\| \leq \tfrac{1}{n} + \tfrac{1}{n} = \tfrac{2}{n};
$$
that is $T(K)$ has a finite $\frac{2}{n}$-net, and hence is relatively compact, because $n$ is arbitrary. Thus $T$ is compact.

Comment: I am a bit lost in the proof. First of all, is $X$ assumed to be Banach? If yes, then the finite rank operators are also bounded, so you don't have to worry about that. Moreover, why is $T_n (X)$ relatively compact? Also, the statement that says there exists an $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have that the supremum is less than $\frac{1}{n}$ feels wrong stated like that. Maybe you mean something slightly different?

Comment: @Esoog Sorry, my answer was full of mistakes and typos. I didn't assume $X$ Banach, there was a typo. I wanted $T_n(K)$ to be relatively compact, not $T_n(X)$. But now I am not sure this works. What do you think? The argument you mention was incorrect (easily fixable), but I tried to rewrite it in a cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I don't remember these stuff so well I am afraid. But wikipedia says that finite rank operators are compact, so that would give the relative compactness of $T_n(K)$.

Comment: @Esoog Thanks to you for pointing out those things! I also studied these things many years ago, so it took me a while to write a decent answer. Finite rank operators are indeed compact, as you say, so I guess that works.